# Commit manually in Django data migration

Tags: django, postgresql, database-migration

I'd like to write a data migration where I modify all rows in a big table in smaller batches in order to avoid locking issues. However, I can't figure out how to commit manually in a Django migration. Everytime I try to run `commit` I get:

> TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.

AFAICT, the [database schema editor always wraps Postgres migrations](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/db/migrations/executor.py#L100) in an [atomic block](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/db/backends/schema.py#L85).

**Is there a sane way to break out of the transaction from within the migration?**

My migration looks like this:

```
def modify_data(apps, schema_editor):
    counter = 0
    BigData = apps.get_model("app", "BigData")
    for row in BigData.objects.iterator():
        # Modify row [...]
        row.save()
        # Commit every 1000 rows
        counter += 1
        if counter % 1000 == 0:
            transaction.commit()
    transaction.commit()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(modify_data),
    ]
```

I'm using Django 1.7 and Postgres 9.3. This used to work with South and older versions of Django.

Comment: For Django 1.10 and above skip to an answer like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74936245/724752

Answer (score 11):

The best workaround I found is manually exiting the atomic scope before running the data migration:

```
def modify_data(apps, schema_editor):
    schema_editor.atomic.__exit__(None, None, None)
    # [...]
```

In contrast to resetting `connection.in_atomic_block` manually this allows using `atomic` context manager inside the migration. There doesn't seem to be a much saner way.

One can contain the (admittedly messy) transaction break out logic in a decorator to be used with the `RunPython` operation:

```
def non_atomic_migration(func):
  """
  Close a transaction from within code that is marked atomic. This is
  required to break out of a transaction scope that is automatically wrapped
  around each migration by the schema editor. This should only be used when
  committing manually inside a data migration. Note that it doesn't re-enter
  the atomic block afterwards.
  """
  @wraps(func)
  def wrapper(apps, schema_editor):
      if schema_editor.connection.in_atomic_block:
          schema_editor.atomic.__exit__(None, None, None)
      return func(apps, schema_editor)
  return wrapper
```

**Update**

Django 1.10 will support [non-atomic migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/writing-migrations/#non-atomic-migrations).

Comment: Django 1.9.5: `AttributeError: 'DatabaseSchemaEditor' object has no attribute 'atomic'`

Answer (score 8):

From [the documentation about `RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runpython):

> By default, RunPython will run its contents inside a transaction on databases that do not support DDL transactions (for example, MySQL and Oracle). This should be safe, but may cause a crash if you attempt to use the schema_editor provided on these backends; in this case, pass atomic=False to the RunPython operation.

So, instead of what you've got:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  operations = [
      migrations.RunPython(modify_data, atomic=False),
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried that but it doesn't actually remove the atomic context around the migration (at least for Postgres).

Comment: Curious, because here's the code in django.db.migration.py: `if not schema_editor.connection.features.can_rollback_ddl and operation.atomic:` - `if not schema_editor.connection.features.can_rollback_ddl and operation.atomic: with atomic(schema_editor.connection.alias): ...`. Are you positive something else isn't going on? Maybe set a breakpoint there (it's line 109 in django 1.8)?

Comment: Yes, this avoids making the operation atomic but the database schema editor still makes the whole migration atomic: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/db/backends/schema.py#L85

Comment: D'oh. On the off chance you didn't think of this, the only way to do it might be just `connection.cursor().execute("COMMIT;")`, though you really wanted a "sane" way. :/ It's definitely not ideal, but it looks like there may be no way around it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that actually works if I also set `connection.in_atomic_block = False`. Looking at the logged SQL statements this actually works fine (BEGIN/COMMIT at the proper spots). However, I get the feeling you're not meant to break out of an atomic block (with sane code). That makes it quiet hard to write more complex data migrations with Django.

Comment: Yeah, OTMH, I very much would assume you're not meant to be meddling with the internal state of that `connection` object. As much as I hate it, it might be better to just use the cursor to execute the COMMIT statement yourself. Or at the very least, save the current state, do your `connection.in_atomic_block = False` inside of a `try` block, and use `finally` to ensure you reset the state to what it was. That at least feels a little less hack-ish. This is all just IMO, of course.

Comment: And this helped. Using MySQL and having a data migration affecting a huge chunk of data `atomic=False` helps!

Answer (score 2):

First you need to set `Migration.atomic = False`

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    atomic = False
```

Then in your function you can wrap certain block of code inside of `transaction.atomic()` to make only that block atomic

```py
from django.db import transaction

for row in rows:
    with transaction.atomic():
        do_something(row)
        # Changes made by `do_something` will be committed by this point
```

Here's the relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/writing-migrations/#non-atomic-migrations

Gotcha: `migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, atomic=False)` does NOT do what you want. It prevents django from **manually** putting your migration code inside a transaction, which it doesn't do for Postgresql anyway. This `atomic=False` option is meant for DBs that don't support DDL transaction, as stated in their documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/migration-operations/#runpython

> By default, RunPython will run its contents inside a transaction on databases that do not support DDL transactions (for example, MySQL and Oracle). This should be safe, but may cause a crash if you attempt to use the schema_editor provided on these backends; in this case, pass atomic=False to the RunPython operation.

> On databases that do support DDL transactions (SQLite and PostgreSQL), RunPython operations do not have any transactions automatically added besides the transactions created for each migration.

Answer (score 0):

For others coming across this. You can have both data (RunPython), in the same migration. Just make sure all the alter tables goes first. You cannot do the RunPython before any ALTER TABLE.